# Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, object given in G:\xampp\htdocs\Project1\login.php on line 11

Tags: php, mysql, warnings

I have made this PHP code but again and again, this warning is coming

> Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, object given in G:\xampp\htdocs\Project1\login.php on line 11

Here is the code enter code here:

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect('localhost','Medical','MED1234','Medicine');
mysqli_select_db($con,'Medicine');


$use= $_POST['user'];
$pas= $_POST['pass'];

$q="select * from login where Username='$use' and Password='$pas' ";
$result=mysqli_query($con,$q);
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);

if($count==1)
{
   header("location: list1.html");    
}

 else
 {
    echo "Wrong Credentials";
 }

mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using `mysql_num_rows()` instead of `mysqli_num_rows()`.